# ProblemMatcher in VS Code using incorrect file for gulp-tslint task

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

tasks.json in .settings of project root

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "gulp",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "dev",
        "args": [],
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        "problemMatcher": [
        "$tsc",
        "$jshint"
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskName": "tslint",
        "fileLocation": ["absolute"],
        "problemMatcher": [
        {
            "pattern": {
            "regexp": "\\[[^\\]]+\\] \\[[^\\]]+\\] (\\S+) \\([^\\)]+\\) ([^\\[]+)\\[(\\d+), (\\d+)\\]: (.+)",
            "file": 2,
            "line": 3,
            "column": 4,
            "severity": 1,
            "message": 5
            }
        }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Example output of tslint task:

```
[17:35:12] [gulp-tslint] error (no-unused-variable) C:\repo\IgnitionOne\stable\prototype-coresettings\src\server\controllers\userController.ts[38, 9]: unused variable: 'test'
```

Unescaped Regex:

```
\[[^\]]+\] \[[^\]]+\] (\S+) \([^\)]+\) ([^\[]+)\[(\d+), (\d+)\]: (.+)
```

When I test my regex on online testing tools, its pulling all the groups out properly. When I look at the problems in vs code with CTRL+SHIFT+M I see the error with file path, name, and message all being correct. However when I click on the error, I get:

> Error opening 'userController.ts' (File not found).

And if I click Create File from there:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir
>   'c:\repo\IgnitionOne\stable\prototype-coresettings\c:'

I've looked it over with a fellow dev and it's not clear why this is happening. It's as if it's using a file location relative to workspace root and matching only 'c:' in the file group. Any ideas on what is not set up correctly?

Comment: On which folder did you open the workspace. If the matcher reports an absolute path we still try to map it back into the workspace root folder. It looks like something goes wrong here.

Comment: c:\repo\IgnitionOne\stable\prototype-coresettings is the workspace folder

Comment: I had a similar problem. I fixed it by putting the `fileLocation` attribute inside of the `problemMatcher`. Here is the relevant fragment from my config file  `"problemMatcher": [{
  "pattern": {
    "regexp": "^([^:]*):(\\d+):(\\d+):(.*)",
    "file": 1,
    "line":2,
    "column":3,
    "messge":4 
  },
  "fileLocation": ["absolute"]
 }]`

Comment: Good catch Leonardo. As the doc here https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/tasks states the fileLocation attribute must be inside of the problemMatcher

Comment: I added code to the JSON schema that should warn about a wrong location of properties.

Comment: Leonardo was right. I was putting fileLocation on the wrong object.